# If $\frac{\sec^8 \theta}{a}+\frac{\tan^8 \theta}{b} = \frac{1}{a+b}\;,$ Then prove that $ab\leq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\displaystyle \frac{\sec^8 \theta}{a}+\frac{\tan^8 \theta}{b} = \frac{1}{a+b}\;,$  Prove that $ab\leq 0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ I am Trying To solve it Using Inequality.

Using $\bf{Cauchy\; Schwartz\; Inequality::}$

$$\frac{(\sec^4 \theta)^2}{a}+\frac{(\tan^4 \theta)^2}{b}\geq \frac{(\sec^4 \theta+\tan^4\theta)^2}{a+b}$$

and equality hold when $$\frac{\sec^4 \theta}{a}=\frac{\tan^4 \theta}{b}$$

Now I did not understand How can I solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trivially, $\sec^8 \theta \ge 1$ and $\tan^8 \theta \ge 0$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\sec \theta$ and $\tan \theta$ are defined.

If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. Then, $\dfrac{\sec^8 \theta}{a}+\dfrac{\tan^8 \theta}{b} \ge \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{0}{b} = \dfrac{1}{a} > \dfrac{1}{a+b}$, a contradiction.

If $a < 0$ and $b < 0$. Then, $\dfrac{\sec^8 \theta}{a}+\dfrac{\tan^8 \theta}{b} \le \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{0}{b} = \dfrac{1}{a} < \dfrac{1}{a+b}$, a contradiction.

Thus, either $a \ge 0$ and $b \le 0$ or $a \le 0$ and $b \ge 0$. Therefore, $ab \le 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{a}+\frac{\tan^2 \theta}{b}=\frac{1}{a+b} = \frac{\sec^2 \theta-\tan^2 \theta}{a+b}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{a(a+b)}\left[(a+b)\sec^2 \theta-a\right]+\frac{\tan^2 \theta}{(a+b)a}\left[(a+b)\tan^2 \theta+b\right]=0$$

$$\Rightarrow\tan^2 \theta+b\sec^2 \theta = 0\Rightarrow \sin^2 \theta=-\frac{b}{a}\geq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow -\frac{b}{a}\geq 0\Rightarrow -ab\geq 0\Rightarrow ab\leq 0$$